# JXBrowser 6.12 - Mouse Event Listener doesn't work

Tags: jxbrowser

I am trailing JXBrowser 6.12. And following this example:

https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013075-keyboard-mouse-events

Key Events were caught just fine. Mouse Events were not caught.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in 6.12 we have already started working on. While we are working on the fix, please use [6.11.1](http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-6.11.1-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip) version where this issue isn't reproducible instead of 6.12.

**UPD**: An official updated build with the fix has been released: http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/jxbrowser-6.13-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

**UPD:** I'm glad to let you know that the issue has been fixed. An updated EAP build with the fix is available for download from http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.13-b10-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

Please try this EAP build and let me know your feedback. The fix will be included into official 6.13 build we are planning to release this week.